# Adding a WebformView to an ASP.NET MVC Core application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, webforms, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a single page Webform application where `default.aspx.cs` file connects to a `SQL Server 2012` database and pulls data via complex queries and displays it on `default.aspx` page. How can we integrate it into an `ASP.NET MVC Core` application that is also using the same SQL Database? Can using [WebFormView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webformview(v=vs.118).aspx) be a choice, if so how? We could not find an example of it. We are using VS2015.

Comment: have you taken a look at the following [MSDN ASP.NET CORE APPLICATION](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html)

Comment: @MethodMan Yes. But that is not using [WebFormView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webformview(v=vs.118).aspx) inside MVC Core app.

Comment: Webforms aren't supported in `ASP.NET Core` projects yet. The only workaround is to create a separate webform project and display the page  in an `iframe` in your `ASP.NET Core` project